# Add split strings to properties in new list

Tags: c#

I'm having a list of strings called "gtinWithId" and looks like this:

```
1:043289235053
2:842372362912
3:672348234722
```

Then I have this class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have this loop to split my list of strings, where my goal is to use the part before ":" as Id.

```
        var listOfProducts = new List<Product>();
        foreach (var gtin in gtinWithId)
        {
            string[] wholeString = gtin.Split(':');
            string idPart = wholeString[0];
            string gtinPart = wholeString[1];

            //TODO
            // I really don't know what to do here to assign each idPart and each gtinPart to
            // the Id-property and the ProductName.propery in my new list

        }
```

Then what I'm trying to do is to populate my "listOfProducts" with every "string idPart" and every "string gtinPart" set as a list of "listOfProducts" properies Id and ProductName.

So the goal is to have a "listOfProducts" that looks something like this:

```
Id = 1 , ProductName = 043289235053
Id = 2 , ProductName = 842372362912
Id = 3 , ProductName = 672348234722
```

Comment: What is it that you do not understand? Please clarify and show what you have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you wrote this code without first learning how to assign a value to a property of an object.

Comment: @Groo I'm sorry, but I dont know how to asign each created string in the foreach to my new listOfProducts

Comment: Pseudo code would be something like: "1) Create a new `Product` instance. 2) Set its `Id` and `ProductName`. 3) Add it to the list." It can be done in a single line as shown in the answer below, but I think you should at least try to write these three lines in C# yourself.

Comment: alright @Groo I've tried to write for it many times before i posted this question. Next time I add my attmpt to the posted question aswell. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close. Just add this in place of your TODO comment:

```
listOfProducts.Add(new Product() { Id = idPart, ProductName = gtinPart });
```

Comment: thank you! I'm very new to the c# language and forget parts of it sometimes. Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness and to allow you to compare alternatives, the simpler solution is to write it "longhand", with this in place of your TODO:

```
Product p = new Product();
p.Id = idPart;
p.ProductName = gtinPart;
listOfProducts.Add(p);
```

This has exactly the same effect as SoftwareFactor's answer above but takes 4 lines instead of 1.

Another solution only works if you have control over the `Product` class, as you appear to in this instance, and that is to add a constructor which allows the setting of the two properties:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product(string id, string productName)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ProductName = productName;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The usage in your TODO would then become this:

```
listOfProducts.Add(new Product(idPart, gtinPart));
```